# Dynamics crm opportunity "actualvalue"

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Since July 2018, the field actualvalue of all opportunities is =0 in our CRM organization. Maybe it is due to the V9 upgrade? Totalamount has still values on the other hand.
Could somebody please tell me when actualvalue is given a value? Our opportunities are  not associated with products. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Actual Revenue(actualvalue)* is updated on opportunity when opportunity status is changed to WON.
Please the image for reference. Hope it helps.
[image]